# How to avoid the double `unwrap()` when getting a string from headers?

Tags: rust, rust-axum

Is there a way to avoid the double `unwrap()` in the below code?

```rust
let cookies = req
  .headers()
  .get("Cookie")
  .map(|c| c.to_str().unwrap_or(""))
  .unwrap_or("");
```

I'm using the [axum](https://crates.io/crates/axum) crate, so `req` is a [`RequestParts`](https://docs.rs/axum/0.5.17/axum/extract/struct.RequestParts.html).

I need `cookies` as `String` or `&str` or empty string if no cookies are present.

Comment: What library is this? You can probably use [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) instead of `map`.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Option::and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.and_then) with [`Result::ok`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.ok):

```rust
let cookies = req
  .headers()
  .get("Cookie")
  .and_then(|c| c.to_str().ok())
  .unwrap_or("");
```

`Option::and_then` is a way to chain `Option`s together. It will automatically unwrap the `Option` returned, if it is `Some`.

`Result::ok` is a way to convert a `Result` into an `Option`. If the `Result` is `Ok(value)`, it will return `Some(value)`, otherwise `None`.